# Fixing the code

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello I would like to ask if there is a better way of converting my code to a better or faster way? As you can see it is a nested if statements. I want it to be a lesser line of code. Any help?

```
$scope.check = function (viewLocation) {
  if(viewLocation == "videos"){
      $scope.icon_video = 'img/video-active.png';
      $scope.icon_events = 'img/events.png';
      $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks.png';
      $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat.png';
  }else{
      if(viewLocation == "events"){
         $scope.icon_video = 'img/video.png';
         $scope.icon_events = 'img/events-active.png';
         $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks.png';
         $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/chat.png';
      }else{
        if(viewLocation == "stocks"){
            $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/video.png'
            $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/events.png'
            $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks-active.png'
            $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat.png'
        }else{
            if(viewLocation == "chat"){
                scope.icon_stocks = 'img/video.png'
                $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/events.png'
                $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks.png'
                $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat-active.png'
            }else{
                scope.icon_stocks = 'img/video.png'
                $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/events.png'
                $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks.png'
                $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat.png'
            }
        }
      }

  }
};
```

Comment: Hey Dren, this is probably better off at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this *might* work:

```
$scope.check = function (viewLocation) {
    $img_arr = array("video","events","stocks","chat");

    foreach($img_arr as $imgcurk => $imgcurv){
        ${"scope.icon_" . $imgcurk} = "img/" . $imgcurk;
        if($imgcurk == viewLocation){
            ${"scope.icon_" . $imgcurk} .= "-active";
        }
        ${"scope.icon_" . $imgcurk} .= ".png";
    }
};
```

Please note, I haven't tested this whatsoever but the theory applies.

Comment: I don't see this code running. Can you please support your answer with working code.

Comment: "This might work" and "I haven't tested this" kinda explain.

Answer (score 1):

one way improving it is :

```
$scope.check = function (viewLocation) {
    $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/video.png'
    $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/events.png'
    $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks.png'
    $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat.png'

    if (viewLocation == "videos") {
        $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat-active.png'
    } else if (viewLocation == "events") {
        $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/events-active.png'
    } else if (viewLocation == "stocks") {
        $scope.icon_stocks = 'img/stocks-active.png'
    } else if (viewLocation == "chat") {
        $scope.icon_chat = 'img/chat-active.png'
    }
};
```

if there is a possibility of having at least one active tab then last 'else if' can just be an 'else'

Comment: Rather than extended if/elseif/else statements which can become unwieldy, have a look at switch/case statements. These provide a great deal of flexibility and are easier to maintain in the future. At the moment the entire chain of code executes if `viewLocation` is chat which may be a little inefficient.

Comment: Um, no. There's no need for me to do that. If you google if/else vs switch you can find out more yourself